# What is it called when a sentence is continued after an ellipsis?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, ellipses

It there a term for when a sentence is broken off by an ellipsis, and then continued?

Consider this example from Terry Pratchett's *Thief of Time* (2001, p. 10):

> “They were… non-life forms.”

I know that "aposiopesis" describes a sentence "broken off and left unfinished" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposiopesis)), but in this case the sentence *is* finished after a break.

I was thinking of calling it an "unfinished sentence" or "incomplete thought", but these too seem inadequate.

Maybe "halting speech" or a "hesitant pause"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes,M. "Halting speech" or a "hesitant pause" would be fine here if the speaker were struggling for the mot juste. I suppose it _could_ be an intended dramatic / highlighting pause by the speaker, though. Ellipses are overworked multi-taskers.

Comment: "Ellipses are overworked multi-taskers"? What the heck is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Halting speech suggests difficulty speaking and would probably have multiple pauses and in odd places, like between "they" and "were". This could be a thoughtful pause showing the speaker trying to decide what they were, or what to call them. Hesitant pause is neutral and I think the better choice here.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a ***pause*** in the flow of the sentence, it does not mark the omission of certain words. [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/articles/use-ellipses-grammar) explains:

> In fiction, an ellipsis can demonstrate ***a pause in dialogue*** or a character "trailing off" (stopping talking without finishing their sentence).
> He stammered, "Please ... tell my son ... that I love him ..."

Note that the two first ellipses are pauses, whereas the third one is "trailing off".

Ellipis can be interpreted in many ways, and in a way, the author leaves it to the reader to decide what it is:

> An ellipsis isn’t just used when you take out words from quoted text. *An ellipsis can also represent **a mood shift, thoughts trailing off, hesitation, pause, or suspense**.* ([Writer](https://writer.com/blog/ellipses/))

I would say your sentence uses ellipses:

> To create a ***pause for effect***. [Grammarmonster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/ellipsis.htm)